# Does spam reputation of my workstation IP affect email deliverability? [with smtp-relay/smart-host]

Tags: email, smtp

I apologize if this is off-topic, I wasn't sure if this should be posted here or on SuperUser.

We had an ISP change at our office and we have a new fixed IP. We have a remote SMTP server.

Today I was using MxToolbox's email header analyzer tool on a test email I sent from my office workstation, and the tool notified me that our new office IP is on a couple blacklists.

I've been searching around and I can't find any reference of the sender machine IP (not email server IP) affecting deliverability. So does it affect it, or did MxToolbox just look up every IP in the headers, regardless whether it's relevant or not?

Comment: Which blacklist?  Some blacklist list "small business" ranges. One "blacklist" lists worse **half** of the internet.

Comment: @AnFi it's a part of a /16 range listed on Spamhaus PBL (which I read is actually benign) and SORBS DUHL

Comment: Hosts in such nets (DUHL/PBL) are **expected and encouraged** to use (trusted) SMTP relay for outgoing mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it unsurprising that MxToolbox checked the headers when asked to do a header check.

There are anti-spam solutions that look at all email headers as part of their evaluation. This includes the apparent origin address rather than just the last hop.

Answer (score 1):

## [PBL](https://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/) & [DUHL](http://www.sorbs.net/faq/dul.shtml) [DNSBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) listing

You mentioned your workstation being listed by:

1. [Spamhaus PBL](https://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/)
2. [SORBS DUHL](http://www.sorbs.net/faq/dul.shtml)

Such listings mean that your IP address should not send email **directly** to recipient SMTP server.
You use smtp-relay/smart-host already so it the above two listings should not be any problem.

Shit happens, overzealous "reject/dev-null happy" idiots too .